# Graph API cannot filter Azure AD B2B users by the phone number used to sign in

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm unable to find users in Azure AD B2C by their phone number used to sign in using the Microsoft Graph API. According [to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), I should be able to query users by their identities as long as I provide `issuer` and `issuerAssignedId` in the filter, but I always receive an empty result set.

I've tried:

- Querying by an email address identity instead. This succeeds.
- Signing in for the first time with the phone number, in case there's some sort of initialization that needs to happen. The user is still not returned.
- Querying by the user attribute `mobilePhone`. [Querying by mobilePhone requires setting ConsistencyLevel=eventual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries), and [ConsistencyLevel=eventual is not supported in Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9856#issuecomment-692414974).

Below is a request that successfully creates a test user, followed by requests trying to find that user by the email address or by the phone number.

The variable `{{B2C_TENANT}}` is the full tenant domain: `example.onmicrosoft.com`.

#### Create user

First, I create the user and give it two sign in identities: One with an email address, one with a phone number.

Request:

```
POST /v1.0/users HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Stephen",
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "asdkljfdklsj2340982304#$#$",
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
    },
    "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuer": "{{B2C_TENANT}}",
          "issuerAssignedId": "stephen@example.com"
        },
        {
            "signInType": "phoneNumber",
            "issuer": "{{B2C_TENANT}}",
            "issuerAssignedId": "+13105551234"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Find user by phone

This request always returns an empty result set, as though no user exists with the given phone number.

Request:

```
GET /v1.0/users/?$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq '{{B2C_TENANT}}' and id/issuerAssignedId eq '+13105551234') HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
```

Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
  "value": []
}
```

#### Find user by email

This request returns the user. If I select the `identities`, I can see it contains the phone number sign in I'm trying to query in the previous request.

Request:

```
GET /v1.0/users/?$filter=identities/any(ident:ident/issuer eq '{{B2C_TENANT}}' and ident/issuerAssignedId eq 'stephen@example.com')&$select=id,userPrincipalName,displayName,identities HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
```

Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,userPrincipalName,displayName,identities)",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "2de83c94-e734-470b-8ca2-c3279c364164",
      "userPrincipalName": "2de83c94-e734-470b-8ca2-c3279c364164@{{B2C_TENANT}}",
      "displayName": "Stephen",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "phoneNumber",
          "issuer": "{{B2C_TENANT}}",
          "issuerAssignedId": "+13105551234"
        },
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuer": "{{B2C_TENANT}}",
          "issuerAssignedId": "stephen@example.com"
        },
        {
          "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
          "issuer": "{{B2C_TENANT}}",
          "issuerAssignedId": "2de83c94-e734-470b-8ca2-c3279c364164@{{B2C_TENANT}}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Graph API: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/13084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL encode the phone number. `%2B13105551234`, then it works.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was something so silly. I guess I was assuming that Postman would URL encode it for me and it never crossed my mind to check for that.